# Python Array with Dicts remove ‚Duplicates‘

Tags: python

I have an array with dicts containing cookie information.
Example:

```
[
    {'domain': '.scrapethissite.com', 'expiry': 1683192201, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_ga', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.2.880485616.1620120162'},
    {'domain': '.scrapethissite.com', 'expiry': 1620206605, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gid', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.2.1342682571.1620120162'},
    {'domain': '.scrapethissite.com', 'expiry': 1627896207, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_fbp', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'fb.1.1620120161975.1281622715'},
    {'domain': '.scrapethissite.com', 'expiry': 1683192205, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_ga', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.2.880485616.1620120162'},
    {'domain': '.scrapethissite.com', 'expiry': 1620206609, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gid', 'path': '/', 'secure': False, 'value': 'GA1.2.1342682571.1620120162'}
]
```

The problem is that I have some duplicates, it’s the same cookie but it has different expiry.
Example: there are two `_gid` and `_ga` Cookies with different expiry dates.

My goal is a function to remove duplicates by creating a result array that only contains every cookie once by adding each key/value “name” only once.

```py
def cookie_remove_duplicates(array):
    # Array for results
    result_array = []
    # go thru array
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        # Get Value for Key 'name' 
        tmp_value_unsorted = array[i].get('name')
        
        if(len(result_array) == 0):
            result_array.append(array[i])
        
        # Go thru results array
        for y in range(0, len(result_array)):
            tmp_value_sorted = result_array[y].get('name')

            
            # if value is not the same add to result array 
            if(tmp_value_sorted != tmp_value_unsorted):
                result_array.append(array[i])
```

The function ends up in a endless loop. I don’t know that I am doing wrong, hope you can help.

Thanks in advance,
Andi

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should in general use `enumerate()` rather than `range(len())`

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, seems like you are adding each new value again for each value that does not match. You want to add it only if none match. Right now if there are 2 cookies you add each new value twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this in one line:

```
def remove_cookie_duplicates(cookies):
    return list({i["name"]: i for i in cookies}.values())
```

### Breakdown

```
{i["name"]: i for i in cookies}
```

This part is a dict comprehension dictionary with the name as a key and the cookie itself as the value. A side-effect of a dictionary is that every key may appear only once. Thus this conversion silently discards any elements with the same name.

Next, I do `.values()` which discards the keys and leaves only the cookies themselves. This returns an iterator, so we do `list()` to convert it finally back into a list.

Comment: oh my gosh thank you so much it is working!!! thanks! can you maybe explain me what the function does? i would love to understand whats happening in that single line thats working out so great :)

Comment: I added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could get this job done much faster and cleaner with the `unique_everseen()` function. Basically what this does is:

> List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen.

To use it you should install the itertools extension for Python:

```
pip install more-itertools
```

Then this line of code will do exactly what you just described at almost C speed.

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

unqie_cookies = unique_everseen(cookies_array, key=lambda c: c['name'])
```

Note:

`unique_everseen()` will **return a generator** if you want to convert it into a list just use `list(unqie_cookies)`

*Oh I just noticed that you only want the cookie names.*